# Does List.ToArray() preserve indices?

Tags: c#

Will the index an item in a `List theList` be the same as its index in `theList.ToArray()`? i.e., does `theList[i]==theList.ToArray()[i]` for sure?  Assuming the answer is yes just want to double check.

Update:

Here is a use case, if you can't imagine this is useful: I am using an optimization routine that accepts an array as input.  Currently my variables are in a list.  I want to run the optimization routine on the variables, then take the result of the optimization routine (which is an array obviously), and put them back in the list.  I want to be sure I can just put them back at their original indices.

Comment: Why don't you use your debugger for this?

Comment: How do you mean? How does that check this in general?

Comment: Yes, `ToArray` preserves order. Wouldn’t be very useful if it didn’t. (And it doesn’t make arrays with non-zero bases, if that’s what you’re asking.)

Comment: Wondering why someone would downvote this.  Is it not a legitimate question? Is it a duplicate? I don't understand this site sometimes.

Comment: @dashnick Not the DV but possible that someone thinks its "not useful"; if you are relying on index order for something you are *usually* doing something wrong in C#

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Um, what? Relying on the ordering of an ordered collection is wrong somehow?

Comment: @Ryan Generally speaking you don't need to index into collections; so the indices matching becomes irrelevant (and relying on this can open code up to bugs).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: That’s a terrible generalization, and “indices matching” is just another way of saying “in the same order”.

Comment: @Ryan Agree to disagree I guess; I'm almost always using `foreach` or LINQ. I'm sure there are still areas that heavily rely on indexing, just not ones I'm aware of/using at the moment. (I agree that indices matching/same order is the same thing though)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  I think Ryans point is, even if your foreach, converting between array and list will maintain things in their same place,  so if your foreach prints out each element, converting between array and list won't change what's printed

Comment: #dashnick,  when you ask a question, don't include the tag in the subject.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Absolutely, I think where we disagree is how important or not that fact is.

Comment: FYI - If you change your optimization routine to accept `IList<T>` instead of `T[]`, you can avoid the O(n) operation, which will perform better than converting using `.ToArray()` and then back using `.ToList()`. Note that `IList<T>` will accept either a `T[]` or a `List<T>`. Ideally, an "optimization" would alter the elements in place for the best performance.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Agreed, but it is third party and don't want to mess with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx) uses [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) under the hood which preserves order.

From Array.Copy

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the first element
>   and pastes them into another Array starting at the first element. The
>   length is specified as a 32-bit integer.

From ToArray

> The elements are copied using Array.Copy, which is an O(n) operation,
>   where n is Count.

Comment: Wonder if there is an explicit interface implementation for the LINQ version. +1 for the "standard" reason why it would work.

Answer (score 6):

LINQ's `ToArray` just enumerates the collection and stuffs the results into an array. `List<T>` enumerates linearly, so yes; the indices will match.

Please note that this is not guaranteed by the .NET specification/documentation, but is unlikely to change.