# C# How to remove a completed Task from Task[]

Tags: c#, arrays, task, .net-4.5

I have an array of tasks running like this: (the number of tasks in the array is not fixed to 2, it can vary from time to time).

```
Task[] templates = new Task[2] {
  Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { x.foo(); }),
  Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { y.bar(); })
};
```

Then I wait for any of them to finish.

```
int taskID;
taskID = Task.WaitAny(templates);
```

As soon a task has finished I inspect various parameters inside the object (x or y) and if I don't have the result I expected I want to remove the finished task from the template array. something like this

```
template[taskID].RemoveThisTaskFromArray() // This is pseudo code to describe what I want.
taskID = Task.WaitAny(templates);
```

I will do this in a loop until the task array `template[]` is empty or I decide to abort the operation and break out of the loop.

```
int taskID;
do {
  taskID = Task.WaitAny(templates);
  if(template[taskID].valid == true) { // <-- example of test for success
    // stop the remaining task in the template[] array.
    break;
  }

  // remove the completed task so we can use WaitAany() again.

} while (template.Length > 0);
```

It seems like `Task[]` doesn't support array members so There is no `Task[].RemoveAt()` function.
I hope you get my point. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [`List<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead. But also, use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` for reasons [described in detail here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

```cs
var templates = new List<Task> {
  Task.Run( () => { x.foo(); }),
  Task.Run( () => { y.bar(); })
};
int taskID;
do {
  taskID = Task.WaitAny(templates.ToArray());
  if(templates[taskID].valid == true) { // <-- example of test for success
    // stop the remaining task in the template[] array.
    break;
  }

  templates.RemoveAt(taskID);

} while (template.Count > 0);
```

This calls `.ToArray()`, which will creates a new array ([preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41818403/1202807)) so is slightly inefficient, but it works. This is really the easiest way to give `Task.WaitAll` the array it's looking for, while preserving your ability to easily remove items.

But I don't know what you're trying to do with `template[taskID].valid`. Did you mean to use your `templates` (with an 's') array? (that's what I assumed) But `Task` doesn't have any property called `valid`. Did you mean to look at the [`Status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status) property?

However, you can consider using `async` and `await` and use [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) to avoid blocking the current thread while you wait. `Task.WhenAll` also accepts any `IEnumerable`, so you don't need to call `.ToArray()`.

```cs
do {
  var doneTask = await Task.WhenAny(templates);

  // This will return any result, but also throw any exception that
  // might have happened inside the task.
  await doneTask;

  templates.Remove(doneTask);

} while (templates.Count > 0);
```

There are some very well-written articles about asynchronous programming, starting here: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try. You are right, I'm not actually testing `Task.Valid`, it was just to illustrate that I'm testing something in relation to the finished task.

Comment: Sorry, but in your first example Task.WaitAny is expecting a Task[]. It gives error on List<T>: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'` And I think you made a typo, List<T> doesn't have the property `Length`, its `Count` (another C# logic)  :)

Comment: Right. I've fixed that. You can use `.ToArray()` to give it what it wants. See my update. (This is another good reason to use `Task.WhenAll`)

Answer (score 1):

Remove completed task from list of Tasks can be done using linq like this

```
templates.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
```

Comment: Nope tried that, Task[] doesn't support RemoveAll() on a Task array: `'Task[]' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAll' and no accessible extension method 'RemoveAll' accepting a first argument of type 'Task[]' could be found`

Comment: make array as list like this `templates.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);`